# Htmlstring table not working in the Open Data Tables

Tags: yql

I found several references online about the YQL HTML table that is no longer supported by Yahoo.
And so I replaced it with the new "htmlstring" table.
When I try to launch a select including the new htmlstring table in the console in the following manner:

```
Select * from htmlstring where URL='myurl' and xpath='/div[@class = "className"]'
```

The correct result is shown in the result panel.

However my code using the old HTML table is originally included in an Open Data Table.
And so I modified my Open Data Table replacing the HTML table with the new htmlstring in the data table code like in the following piece of code of example:

```xml
<meta>
  <sampleQuery>
    select * from {table} where url="http://myurl" and wparams="1,2,4,5,6" and xpath='//div[@class = "className"]'
  </sampleQuery>
</meta>
```

```js
var results = y.query("select * from htmlstring where url=@url and xpath=@xpath", {url:url, xpath:xpath}).results.*;
```

Unfortunately in this last case the query launched by the `y.query ()` method return a null value, while the old code referring to the old HTML table, worked fine.
Why does the new htmlstring table not work if included in an Open Data Table while there are no problems excluding the Open Data Table?
Is there any reference I forgot to include in the open data table's code?